# MSVS 2013 "step into" steps in a non-consistent manner

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, breakpoints

I'm working on a pure C++/OpenGL project without .NET or other specific libs, just pure C++ syntax with pure OpenGL code. I use Windows 8.1 and MSVS 2013 Community with update 4.
I set a breakpoint and at debugging it paused as expected and from there I continued with F10/F11 to go from line to line and skip the code that wasn't mine.
It showed the line marker for the line about to be executed, just fine until I was in some function and as I hit F10 it just skipped 3 lines like that, with no reason, conditional or otherwise. After another F10 it returned to the line it supposed to go in the first place and continued correctly.

Today after adding some files and some code, MSVS 2013 debugger wouldn't break at any breakpoints at all. After 6 hours of repairing, uninstalling and installing MSVS 2013 Express (with which BTW the project was incompatible (?!)) and MSVS Community 2013, the debugger paused again at breakpoints but still F11 jumps randomly at a point. Here is the part of the code:

```
void loop()
    {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // BREAKPOINT!, press F10
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // marker here, I press again F10

    RenderActionObjects(); // the marker is now at this line
          // before this is executed, I press F11 and it gets me inside ifstream.h!
          // I input a char; from there I step out with shift+F11 which
          // places the marker back at the function call above!
          // I press F11 again and it gives an _expected_ unhandled exception related
          // to some OpenGL (in nvoglv64.dll) and places the marker...
    glfwSwapBuffers(window0); // ... at this line
    glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

`loop()` is repeatedly called in `main()`.

```
static void RenderActionObjects() // looped
    {
    int test;
    test = userAcknowledge; // userAcknowledge is int defined globally
    cin >> userAcknowledge;

    glUseProgram(programsI[0]);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOaction);
    OutputDebugString("testing string"); // HERE is the added line! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, testTex);
    // set uniforms
    glUniform1i(testTex, 0); // 0 as in GL_TEXTURE0 (texture unit 0)

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
```

Please give me a hand if you can, tell me what to try.

What's wrong with `Whitesmiths`? If you bother to edit for this reason, at least make them all the same instead of partly `C-style`, partly `Whitesmiths`.

**EDIT:**
The issue has been reduced to:
With MSVS 2013 debugger if you have multiple nested functions and each function starts with assignments/OpenGL functions prior to calling the further-in-stack function, then pressing F11 the marker jumps from the first function call line directly to the deepest function, and thus not showing the execution path line by line.

Then how can I achieve stepping **from one line to the next** along the execution path?

Comment: Are you compiling in `Debug` or `Release` mode?

Comment: @MikeMB Wow that was fast. In Debug, x64.

Comment: Do you have other breakpoints set in your code? Do you have more than one thread?

Comment: Your problem sounded familiar. The usual reasons are that the version of the source file is not the same as the one you compiled (e.g. forgot to save) or you are running `Release` mode and due to optimizations, there is no proper mapping between a position in the binary and a line in the source code (reordering, inlining, constant propagation, code elimination...) but that is apparently not your problem.

Comment: Make sure your project is actually a `Debug` one by making sure that the optimization in the project settings is set to `None`.  Also, ensure you are actually debugging the build you're running.  If you want confirmation, put an `OutputDebugString()`somewhere in your code and see when you run, that message appears in the Output Window of the debugger.

Comment: If your code is multithreaded, it may be stepping for another thread.

Comment: Thank you all. I use 1 thread; no other breakpoints. I saved multiple times, cleaned and rebuilt.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added `OutputDebugString()` and updated the code in the question and now stepping into with F11 makes the marker jump from `main(){...}` where `loop();` is called directly to `cin >> userAcknowledge;` in `RenderActionObjects(){...}`. I noticed a pattern: with F11 debugger always skips variable declarations and assignments, and skips OpenGL functions only if the line before was also skipped. Normally OpenGL lines are not skipped. It also skips `{` in the same conditions as OpenGL lines. So it's *not* random. Does it make sense?

Comment: I edited the question and made it much more clear.

Comment: @mireazma Did you see the message from OutputDebugString() in the output window?  The goal was to establish that you are actually running the program that you're debugging.  If you didn't see the string, then you are not running the program you're changing.  Run the program in the debugger without any breakpoints first.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks. I saw the string. I don't know what to do anymore as it's a MSVS 2013 bug, apparently. Or what am I missing? If you use MSVS can you tell me how do you personally step from line to line even in nested functions that start with assignments?

Comment: @mireazma It sounds more like you are running a release build.  Did you check your Debug options to ensure that your optimization level for the compiler is set to "None"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't know how exactly to do this; I can't find anything named "optimization" or alike, in debugging options or at least in project properties.

Comment: It is in your project properties for C/C++ settings.  It should be in "Code Generation".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for staying with me so far; I found it, it's set to `Disabled (/Od)`. I've changed the code and added a class and now when I instantiate it, using  F11 makes the marker jump from the object declaration inside the constructor at the opening brace (as intended so far), but F10 sends it back, outside the constructor, *before* the constructor definition, then again inside at the first line after the opening brace.